# Wifi driver hard blocked after suspend - Airplane mode in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, suspend, rtl8723be

I am using HP Pavilion. The wifi switches off and the Airplane mode is switched ON after a suspend. It prompts me to use the Hardware Switch to disable it. But that does not work.

From what I have observed, after this happens, even if I plug in an external wifi adapter, it refuses to work! I don't believe the issue has something to do with Wifi per se, but a deeper rooted problem

This is a common issue that I have looked over in the internet. None of the solutions have worked for me. List of solutions I've tried:

- `/etc/init.d/network-manager restart`
- `service network-manager restart`
- `sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service`
- `rfkill unblock all`
- `sudo rfkill list`

This produced:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

- `nmcli nm sleep false` which gave me `Error: argument 'nm' not understood. Try passing --help instead.`
- `nmcli r wifi off && nmcli r wifi on`
- `nmcli general permissions`

This gave me:

```
PERMISSION                                                        VALUE 
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-network             yes   
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-wifi                yes   
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-wwan                yes   
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-wimax               yes   
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.sleep-wake                         no    
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.network-control                    yes   
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.share.protected               yes   
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.share.open                    yes   
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.system             yes   
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.own                yes   
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.hostname           auth  
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.global-dns         auth  
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.reload                             auth  
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.checkpoint-rollback                auth  
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-statistics          yes   
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-connectivity-check  yes
```

- `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

This gave me:

```
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:804c]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
    Kernel modules: rtl8723be
```

- `lspci -knn | grep Ether -A2`

This gave me:

```
09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 0a)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [103c:8096]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
```

- `sudo rmmod r8169 && sudo modprobe r8169`
- `sudo lshw -class network`

Output:

```
  *-network DISABLED        
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 00
       serial: 70:77:81:bf:70:0d
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be driverversion=4.15.0-20-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:18 ioport:5000(size=256) memory:c6100000-c6103fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 0a
       serial: 3c:a8:2a:bc:22:b3
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8107e-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:52 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:c6004000-c6004fff memory:c6000000-c6003fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: enp0s20u1
       serial: 32:34:f6:b6:94:0e
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.143 link=yes multicast=yes
```

- `sudo apt update`
- `sudo apt dist-upgrade`
- `lspci`

Output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev e3)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev e3)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev e3)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev e3)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev e3)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 03)
08:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 0a)
0a:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 940M] (rev a2)
```

- `dmesg | egrep 'wmi|rtl|hp'`

Output:

```
[    0.000000] clocksource: hpet: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 133484882848 ns
[    0.000000] hpet clockevent registered
[    0.036390] acpiphp: ACPI Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.5
[    0.276037] hpet0: at MMIO 0xfed00000, IRQs 2, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
[    0.276044] hpet0: 8 comparators, 64-bit 14.318180 MHz counter
[    0.278065] clocksource: Switched to clocksource hpet
[    0.674100] pciehp 0000:00:1c.1:pcie004: Slot #1 AttnBtn- PwrCtrl- MRL- AttnInd- PwrInd- HotPlug+ Surprise+ Interlock- NoCompl+ LLActRep+
[    0.899214] rtc_cmos 00:01: alarms up to one month, 242 bytes nvram, hpet irqs
[    1.056592] wmi_bus wmi_bus-PNP0C14:00: WQ data block query control method not found
[    1.056595] wmi_bus wmi_bus-PNP0C14:00: WQ data block query control method not found
[    1.056598] wmi_bus wmi_bus-PNP0C14:00: WQ data block query control method not found
[    1.056600] wmi_bus wmi_bus-PNP0C14:00: WQ data block query control method not found
[    1.056823] wmi_bus wmi_bus-PNP0C14:01: WQBC data block query control method not found
[    1.056850] wmi_bus wmi_bus-PNP0C14:01: WQBJ data block query control method not found
[    1.406258] ata2.00: ATAPI: hp      DVDRW  DU8A6SH, DH61, max UDMA/133
[    1.445218] scsi 1:0:0:0: CD-ROM            hp       DVDRW  DU8A6SH   DH61 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[   21.801406] shpchp: Standard Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.4
[   21.819430] hp_accel: laptop model unknown, using default axes configuration
[   21.874652] rtlwifi: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[   21.874720] rtlwifi: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[   21.893336] hp_wmi: query 0xd returned error 0x5
[   21.893897] rtl8723be: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8723befw_36.bin
[   21.901113] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x15/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   22.129284] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'rtl_rc'
[   22.129600] rtlwifi: rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
[   22.253606] rtl8723be 0000:08:00.0 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
[   22.936466] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Your touchpad (PNP: SYN1ef2 SYN1e00 SYN0002 PNP0f13) says it can support a different bus. If i2c-hid and hid-rmi are not used, you might want to try setting psmouse.synaptics_intertouch to 1 and report this to linux-input@vger.kernel.org.
[   23.014105] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Touchpad model: 1, fw: 8.1, id: 0x1e2b1, caps: 0xd00123/0x840300/0x12e800/0x0, board id: 2997, fw id: 1665536
[  137.112311] hp_wmi: bad event status 0x5
[ 4818.272734] pciehp 0000:00:1c.1:pcie004: Slot(1): Link Down
[ 4818.274010] rtlwifi: rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
[ 4862.465069] pciehp 0000:00:1c.1:pcie004: Slot(1): Link Down
[ 4862.466258] rtlwifi: rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
[ 7062.841235] pciehp 0000:00:1c.1:pcie004: Slot(1): Link Down
[ 7062.842172] rtlwifi: rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
```

- I also tried re-installing the drivers :(

["No wifi adapter found" in settings - screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Np93a.png)

I have attached the output of this command `wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info && \
chmod +x wireless-info && \
./wireless-info`

https://www12.zippyshare.com/v/gBZnOz7G/file.html

This has become increasingly difficult to work with. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Run in a terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-hp-wmi.conf <<< "blacklist hp_wmi"
```

and reboot.

Comment: Has no effect. Tried several times with and without that file, rebooting, suspending with no difference.

Comment: @JohnAnderson Do you have the same laptop as the OP? It may be a BIOS issue.

Comment: My laptop is different, but it is an HP (Envy instead of Pavilion), and my wireless is an Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260. But I see exactly the same behavior as the OP. By the way,  I also see this occasionally on boot and thought it may be related.